# Copy the latest artifact in the artifactory CURL

Tags: shell, artifactory, artifacts

i have repo of snapshots like this:
[www.arifactoryrepo.com/maven-last-dev/com/api/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT](http://www.arifactoryrepo.com/maven-last-dev/com/api/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT)
In the snapshot directory i have a lot of of zip files:

- morad-2.3.5-20201207_291847218.zip
- morad-2.3.5-20201107_291847218.zip
- morad-2.3.5-20201007_291847218.zip

when i click on the link of:
[www.arifactoryrepo.com/maven-last-dev/com/api/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT/morad-2.3.5-SNAPSHOT.zip](http://www.arifactoryrepo.com/maven-last-dev/com/api/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT/morad-2.3.5-SNAPSHOT.zip)
it downloads for me the latest snapshot (morad-2.3.5-20201207_291847218.zip)

I need to copy the latest one to another path, so i used this command:

```
curl -u <USER:PASS> -X post "www.arifactoryrepo.com/artifactory/api/copy/maven-last-dev/com/api/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT.zip?to=/another/path.
```

and i get error of "failed to copy" maybe because the link is redirected.

so, there is anyway to copy the latest artifact ?

Thanks,
Morad.

Answer (score 0):

The copy REST API does not support the translation of Maven unique snapshots.
You can use the artifact [latest version API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout) in order to get the correct version and then use it for the copy API, for example:

```
VERSION=$(curl -uuser:pass "https://myrepo.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/search/latestVersion?g=com.api&a=morad&v=2.3.5-SNAPSHOT&repos=libs-snapshot-local")
curl -uuser:pass -XPOST "https://myrepo.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/copy/libs-snapshot-local/com/api/moard/2.3.5-SNAPSHOT/morad-$VERSION.zip?to=/libs-snapshot-local/copy/me"
```